Fixing imports in python for qiskit problem of writing a quantum phase estimation algorithm
# Step 1: Install Qiskit and matplotlib for plotting
! pip install qiskit-aer
! pip install qiskit qiskit-nature matplotlib

# Step 2: Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.problems import ElectronicStructureProblem
from qiskit_nature.second_q.converters import QubitConverter
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper
from qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver,     VQEUCCFactory
from qiskit.opflow import PauliTrotterEvolution, EvolvedOperatorAnsatz

the imports on the last 4 lines are wrong for the current version of qiskit- does anyone know what the right version is? I'm trying to run this as python in google colab.
Thanks :)
I've tried googling and nothing has really helped even on qiskit website so not sure what the right version is.

It looks like your code is written for version 0.5 and your Google Collab is now importing version 0.6. In version 0.6 the QubitConverter class and EigensolverFactory were deprecated and replaced with a new version. Documentation on how to migrate your code to use these in version 0.6 is available at https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-nature/blob/main/docs/migration/0.6_a_intro.rst
